# Запятая не требуется после слова "бюджета"?

Tags: пунктуация

Исходя из изложенного, в связи с ограниченностью средств республиканского бюджета в целях недопущения нарушения жилищных прав детей предлагаем увеличить размер субсидий...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Исходя из изложенного, в связи с ограниченностью средств республиканского бюджета и в целях недопущения нарушения жилищных прав детей предлагаем увеличить размер субсидий..**

***Исходя из изложенного*** – общее обособленное обстоятельство, отнесенное ко всему предложению.  Далее следуют два сближенных по значению обстоятельства, которые в данном случае **можно считать однородными.**

**Их нужно объединить союзом И**, чтобы отличать от общего обстоятельства в начале предложения.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь два независимых основания для предлагаемого действия, поскольку сложившаяся ограниченность не может существовать "в целях недопущения". Поэтому два соответствующих выражения нужно либо запятой разделить, либо соединить союзом "и", что предпочтительно. Не совсем понятно без дополнительного контекста, почему "в связи с *ограниченностью*" предлагается *увеличить траты* (возникает вопрос, из того же это источника или из другого).

Comment: Вероятно, увеличение субсидий обходится дешевле других вариантов решения вопроса (выделения жилья и т.п.).

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, запятая нужна. Здесь можно увидеть однородные обстоятельства причины.
Если запятую не ставить, то получится, что ограниченность средств возникла в целях недопущения нарушения прав детей.

Кроме того, думаю, после слова *детей* желательна запятая. Часто запятая ставится после распространенного обстоятельственного оборота, стоящего в начале предложения.

Дополнение.
Согласен с Jasmin. Однородные обстоятельства нужно объединить союзом И, чтобы отличать от общего обстоятельства в начале предложения.